# Problem with finite sum. Negative upper limit

Tags: summation

I have a simple code:

```
Sum[-Gamma[k + 1, x], {k, 0, -2}]
(* 0 *)
```

but `Maple` gives `ExpIntegralE[1, x]`

[image]

**Why  MMA gives zero?**

In simple cases works.

```
 Sum[k, {k, 1, -n}] /. n -> 5
 (*10*)
```

[image]

**EDITED:**

```
Sum[k^2, {k, 0, 2}]
(* 5 *)
Sum[k^2, {k, -2, 0}]
(* 5 *)
```

but:

```
Sum[k^2, {k, 0, -n}] /. n -> 2
(*-1 *)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you replace GAMMA with an undefined function like f in Maple, you would get -f(0,x). It seems that  Maple and Mathematica use different summation conventions when dealing with negative upper limit.
2. Sum in Mathematica, in this situation, returns 0 for any upper limit that's smaller than the lower limit. As for -n, it doesn't necessarily imply it's less than 1 so a symbolic expression is returned. Then, you get your (desired maybe?) result with ReplaceAll.
3. Don't use upper limit that's smaller than the lower limit in either programs, unless you are sure about what it does.

Answer (score -1):

The algorithmic convention in *Mathematica* is to *increment* the iteration variable:

```
Sum[-Gamma[k + 1, x], {k, -2, 0}]
```

(* -E^-x - Gamma[-1, x] - Gamma[0, x] *)

$-e^{-x}-\Gamma (-1,x)-\Gamma (0,x)$

Also, one could change variables and compute:

```
Sum[-Gamma[k,x], {k, -1, 1}]
```

If this does not yield the correct answer, then there must be a problem (bug?) or lack of consistency in the definition or symbol conventions of `Gamma` between *Maple* and *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk:  Then the problem has nothing to do with summations and iteration limits.

Comment: ... and due to the definition of `Gamma[-2,x]`.